# How to notifyItemRemove fragments in FragmentStateAdapter in viewpager2

Tags: kotlin, android-viewpager2, fragmentstateadapter

I wanna remove item from viewpager2 adapter but when notify adapter(FragmentStateAdapter) activity crashed and give bellow error:

```
   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 36, Size: 36
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
    at com.libramee.ui.category.adapter.CategoryPagerAdapter.remove(CategoryPagerAdapter.kt:61)
    at com.libramee.ui.home.fragment.HomeFragment$observe$2.onChanged(HomeFragment.kt:218)
    at com.libramee.ui.home.fragment.HomeFragment$observe$2.onChanged(HomeFragment.kt:45)
```

**HomeFragment.kx:**

```
  deleteCategoryLiveData?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        if (it.status == Response.Status.SUCCESS){              
            adapter?.remove(it.message ?:"")            
        }
    })
```

**CategoryPagerAdapter.kx**

```
class CategoryPagerAdapter(fragment: Fragment, var categoryFragments: ArrayList<Fragment>) : 
   FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return categoryFragments.size
}

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
    return categoryFragments.get(position)
}

fun setFragments(categoryFragments: ArrayList<Fragment>){
//    this.categoryFragments.clear()
    this.categoryFragments.addAll(categoryFragments)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}


fun setNewFragments(categoryFragments: ArrayList<Fragment>){
    this.categoryFragments.clear()
    this.categoryFragments.addAll(categoryFragments)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

fun addFragment(categoryFragment: Fragment){
    this.categoryFragments.add(categoryFragment)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

fun remove(index: Int){
    if (itemCount > 0) {
        this.categoryFragments.removeAt(itemCount - 1)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
fun remove(categoryId: String){
    categoryFragments.forEachWithIndex { i, it ->
        if (it is CategoryProductFragment){
            if (it.categoryId.equals(categoryId)){
                categoryFragments.removeAt(i) // i == 34
                notifyItemRangeChanged(0, categoryFragments.size)
                notifyDataSetChanged()
                return@forEachWithIndex
            }
        }
    }
}
fun getAllFragments(): ArrayList<Fragment> {
    return categoryFragments
}
```

}

**is use remove function and removed *index(i)* is 34:**

```
  fun remove(categoryId: String){
    categoryFragments.forEachWithIndex { i, it ->
        if (it is CategoryProductFragment){
            if (it.categoryId.equals(categoryId)){
                categoryFragments.removeAt(i) // i == 34
                notifyItemRangeChanged(0, categoryFragments.size)
                notifyDataSetChanged()
                return@forEachWithIndex
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I dont have any idea for fixed this error!
*Do you know how can I fixed this error????*

Comment: Get position using Fragment Class name. So that it get the current position of the fragment.